# Dataframe set values using square bracket, doesn't follow the order of Dataframe passed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=[0,1])
b = pd.DataFrame([[5,6], [6,7]], columns=[1,0])

a[[0, 1]] = b
print(a)
```

result in

```
   0  1
0  5  6
1  6  7
```

shouldn't it replace `a` with the same column in `b`, which results in:

```
   0  1
0  6  5
1  7  6
```

it's a little confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for select all rows with `list` for columns names:

```
a.loc[:, [0, 1]] = b
print(a)
   0  1
0  6  5
1  7  6
```

Or:

```
cols = [0,1]
a[cols] = b[cols]
print(a)
   0  1
0  6  5
1  7  6
```

Comment: thanks. This seems to work. Maybe my way is not the recommended way.